# How to have equal value horizontal constraints with dynamic value

Tags: ios, storyboard, constraints

I have 3 items in a row horizontally (values are examples and not real values):

```
<----100p----> LABEL <-3p-> IMAGE <-3p-> LABEL <----100p---->
```

I need the two 100p constraints to always be in equal value to one another, but the value can be less than or equal to 100p. The 3p constraint between the Labels and Image must always be 3p. For example, on smaller devices, the two 100p constraints might drop to 50p each to keep the whole structure centered on the smaller screen while maintaining the size of the Labels and Image as well as the 3p constraint.

How can I design my constraints with these requirements? I keep running into a problem where the three elements get off centered on different devices because I can't get two equal but scaling constraints from the view to the Labels.

Made simple: I need the two Labels to always be equidistant (value does not matter) from the view while also maintaining the 3p constraint and size/scale of the Labels & Image.

EDIT:

If I try to keep equal widths for the label, then on smaller screens, the label text does not fit inside within its width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the labels and the image inside of a horizontal stack view.

   - You can do this from your current state by holding down Command on the keyboard and clicking on each of the views. Once they are all highlighted go through the top menu to `Editor > Embed In > Stack View`.
2. Add a constraint to center the stack view in its superview (the main view?).
3. Set the stack view `Distribution` to `Fill` and the `Spacing` to `3` (for your 3p spacing).
4. Set equal width constraints between the two labels so they always keep the same width.
5. On each label go to the `Size Inspector` and set their `Horizontal Compression Resistance Priority` to 1000 (Required) so that they do not get squished into not displaying all of their text. You may need to do this for the image as well if it gets squished. Alternatively you could set a minimum width constraint or fixed width constraint on the image (see next step).
6. Decide how to handle the image width.

   - Option 1: Set no fixed width constraints on any of the labels or image and set the image's `Horizontal Content Hugging Priority` to be either higher or lower than the `Horizontal Content Hugging Priority` of the labels to determine whether the image will stretch to fill the stack view or the labels will stretch to fill the stack view.
   - Option 2: Set a fixed with constraint on either the image OR the labels to keep them the width you want them and have the other view (without the fixed width constraint) stretch to fill.
7. Add an equal widths constraint between the stack view and its super view (the main view, or safe area, whichever you need) and set the `Priority` of the constraint (found in the `Size Inspector` with the constraint selected) to 750 (less than 1000) and the `Constant` to -200.

   - The Constant of -200 tells it that you want the stack view's width to be 200 less than the width of the main view (100 on each side like you wanted).
   - The priority of less than `1000 (Required)` means that it is okay for this constraint to break if necessary to fulfill the other higher priority requirements that you have defined. This is what will allow the 100 spacing on each side to shrink to a lower value if necessary on smaller screens.

I brought up a new storyboard and tested this myself with various size screens and it worked for me. There were a couple variables I was unsure of like how you wanted to handle the label widths and image width but I am unable to comment on posts.